# Using OpenSSL in FIPS mode with .NET

Tags: .net, c, build, openssl, fips

I've build OpenSSL FIPS container version 2.0.1, then built OpenSSL 1.0.1c using that container (according to the instructions in *User Guide for the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0*):

```
SET FIPSDIR=C:\OpenSSL\FIPS

cd C:\OpenSSL\openssl-fips-2.0.1
ms\do_fips

cd C:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.1c
ms\do_nasm
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```

I've got these imports in my .NET application (which is obviously using the libeay32.dll from above):

```
[DllImport("libeay32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static void ERR_load_crypto_strings();

[DllImport("libeay32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int ERR_print_errors_fp(SafeHandle file);

[DllImport("libeay32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int FIPS_mode_set(int onoff);
```

The problem is, that when I call `FIPS_mode_set(1)`, it is returning `0`, which indicates that FIPS mode could not be enabled.

To try and find out why the problem is, I'm doing this:

```
ERR_load_crypto_strings();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream...)
{
  ERR_print_errors_fp(fs.SafeFileHandle);
}
```

Which gives me this error message:

`OPENSSL_Uplink(0FAF1000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink`

I've tried searching for answers, but have come up empty - any suggestions would be much appreciated!

### ** **UPDATE** **

I tried building it using the same steps from a Visual Studio 2008 commandline instead of a Visual Studio 2010 commandline (which I had previously used) - and it worked!

But I have no clue why it won't work with Visual Studio 2010, and I don't want to keep Visual Studio 2008 hanging around forever - any idea how I can get it to build OK with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_Applink.html

Comment: @alk Nope - Peter already posted a link to that, and I'd seen it before in any case. As I mentioned in my response to Peter, I'm not linking the OpenSSL library into my code - I'm using it with .NET via pinvoke

Comment: Regarding the OPENSSL_Applink error I ran into that as well when writing my own DLL to call libeay32. The issue comes from mixing C and C++. If you use the BIO routines for file IO and then call them FROM C++ (and all file io happens in C) then the issue should go away. I got the hint from this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066318/how-to-generate-rsa-sha-signature-using-openssl-in-c#comment40172578_24075424

Answer (score 1):

I have searched in vain for complete instructions on how to build an OpenSSL FIPS capable executable and only found frustration and dead ends. I have finally, through numerous trial and error runs, found the following to work without any build errors. I am posting my findings here in hopes that it will help a poor soul out there looking for a solution to this build problem (and hopefully save them the few hairs they still have left on their heads!).

Summary of how to generate FIPS 140-2 OpenSSL executable and libraries:
(The build machine used is a Windows 7 Ultimate).

Do the following steps as 'Administrator'!!!

1- Install ActiveState Perl and make sure environment path includes the bin folder where Perl has been installed. (See http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)

2- Install Nasm and add path to %PATH% environment variable. (See http://sourceforge.net/projects/nasm)

3- Install Visual Studio 2008 Pro if not already installed (VS2010/2012/2013 do *NOT* seem to build correctly!!).

4- Unpack OpenSSL-FIPS-2.0.9 src distribution to a new folder (do *NOT* reuse a previous folder of the same!).

5- Unpack OpenSSL-1.0.2 src distribution to a new folder (again: do *NOT* reuse a previous folder of the same!).

6- Launch a Visual Studio 2008 DOS command window (Start->Programs->MS Visual Studio 2008->Visual Studio DOS Command WIndow).

7- In that DOS window: "Set FIPSDIR=C:\OpenSSL-FIPS-2.0.9" (or whichever folder name hosts the OpenSSL-FIPS-2.0.9 src distribution just unpacked in step 4 above. Also: Should specify absolute path for FIPSDIR!!!).

8- If building for x86 target, then make sure to: 'Set PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86' from that DOS command window. (Else link failures!).

9- CD C:\OpenSSL-FIPS-2.0.9 (or equivalent) and type: 'ms\ms_fips'. Should see 'BUILD SUCCESS' at end of build.

10- CD C:\OpenSSL-1.0.2 and type the following in sequence at the DOS prompt:

```
    -Perl Configure VC-WIN32 fips --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-FIPS209
        (C:\Build-OpenSSL-FIPS209 will contain the build results when invoking 'INSTALL'. See below.)

    -ms\do_nasm  (ms\do_ms is NOT acceptable for FIPS-140-2 certification! Will use MASM instead of NASM)
        (For DEBUG versions then use flag debug-VC-WIN32 instead, then open ms\nt.mak after executing ms\do_nasm and replace all occurrences of /Zi with /Z7. There should be three replacements. For 64-bit, use VC-WIN64A and ms\do_win64a. If ECP source distros were used in generating the FIPS library in the first step, then    corresponding "FIPS capable" OpenSSL must be built with the no­ec2m option.)

    -nmake -f ms\nt.mak  (for static libs. To build shared libs use: ntdll.mak)

    -nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

11- Done. Verify that the (--prefix) folder 'C:\Build-OpenSSL-FIPS209' now contains the libraries, executable file and header files.

Answer (score 0):

In the openssl documentation there is [mention](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG2) of this error that suggests that you have not created and compiled/linked an appropriate [applink](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_Applink.html).

Alternatively, I think possibly this error might occur if you've not linked the openssl library in with code with the correct runtime (e.g. /MD if you're compiling c/c++ wrapper code).

Comment: I'm not linking the OpenSSL library into my code - I'm using it with .NET via pinvoke. I've been able to get version 1.0.0d working OK, but performance is better in version 1.0.1d (which I can't get to work, as in the question)

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of is that the CRT isn't initialized propertly when openssl is run.  Maybe pinvoking `__crt_dll_initialize`  before calling `FIPS_mode_set`.  As far as I know that's only needed with a mixed-mode application.  Are you writing any managed C++ somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake above - it was version 0.9.8x that I got working, *not* 1.0.0d (which I believe is not compatible with the FIPS container at all)

Answer (score -1):

Try better using this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/ - it will save you lot's of questions.

OpenSSL is complex, hence the C# wrapper library is really good help. To use OpenSSL you need to use pinvoke, which this library definitely does.

Alternativelly you could use external utility stunnel http://www.stunnel.org/index.html, or use openssl direclty thru exec(), and this way you can gain more stability per operation, in case the .NET library doesnt perform well.

It would be really recommended to use WIndows Crypto API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388162(v=vs.85).aspx as it's standard based, it works the same way, thru C# and even MSIE, using the system certificate repository, which does also imports and exports.

Comment: Does openssl.net wrap the FIPS library?

Comment: Are you kidding? :-) I would rewrite openssl before making it work this way.

Comment: OP asked about FIPS.  I assume FIPS is *required*.  Re-writing openssl won't get FIPS certification.  So, I'd have to ask: are *you* kidding?

Comment: @PeterRitchie openssl-net wraps the native openssl library. The included build is probably not FIPS compliant, but you probably can substitute your own build.

Comment: I'm not overly fond of openssl-net though. Last time I checked they got the calling convention wrong, had a few other bugs, and their high level code was rather dubious.

Comment: FIPS *is* required, and the OpenSSL libraries distributed with OpenSSL.NET do not use the FIPS container. I cannot substitute it with my own build, because... well, that's what my question is! When I try to use my own build with .NET I get that error

Comment: @AndrewSmith I don't want to use the built-in .NET crypto stuff, for performance reasons (yes, that is an issue for the application in question). For example, SHA-384 is 3x faster in OpenSSL

Comment: @CodesInChaos CallingConvention has been 'fixed' (behavior changed in later .NET runtimes). Some other bugs have been fixed. Can you shoot me an email/bug report on the high level code you find dubious? The crypto wrapper is much more mature than the SSL wrapper.