# How to generate RSA SHA signature using OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, sha

I need some help using OpenSSL to generate a signature of a block of data using C (Windows and Linux). The application has to do with Google authentication.  The instructions from Google's documentation are:

"Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN
with the SHA-256 hash function) with the private key obtained from the Google Developers Console. The
output will be a byte array."

The private key is a .p12 file containing 1660 bytes of binary data.

Do I use the RSA_sign() API for this?  If so am I supposed to hash the data first?  Using what
key value?  I assume the RSA * parameter is supposed to hold the private key?  How does it get
loaded?  I have used the HMAC function to generate a SHA hash, but I'm a bit lost here - any help
or sample code would be appreciated.  (And yes, I know Google has libraries to do this, but none
for C, which I need to use).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `RSA_sign` to sign the data with SHA256 hash. You can call this

```
RSA_sign(NID_sha256, digest, digest_len, &sign_buffer, sign_len, rsa_key);
```

You have calculate SHA256 hash of the data into `digest` buffer. `rsa_key` should be initialized.

Since, you have `.p12` file, you need to do the following.

Create `PKCS12` structure from `.p12` file.

```
PKCS12 * p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp_to_p12_file, NULL);
```

Parse the `p12` structure to certificate and key.

```
PKCS12_parse(p12, passphrase, &evp_pkey, &x509_cert, NULL);
```

It will give `EVP_PKEY` structure from which you can get `RSA` structure using `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA` or access `evp_pkey->pkey.rsa` member of the structure.

This should help you to start.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I was trying to test this in Windows DLL, and on the call to d2i_PKCS12_fp() I get a runtime error: "OPENSSL_Uplink(03CE1000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink".  Reading up on this error, I gather all I should need to do is include "applink.c" in my project, and call CRYPTO_malloc_init(), which I have done, but it has no effect.  Any ideas about this?

Comment: Did you try OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms first?

Comment: No luck with that - I think the basic problem has to do with the memory model of my dll vs. that used in the OpenSSL libraries, specifically with regard to calling the C runtime library for fopen, fread, etc.  If there was a way that I could confine file operations to my code, read the .p12 file myself, and just pass a buffer when creating the PKCS12 structure, that would work, but I don't see any option for that.

Comment: @Jeff OpenSSL-Windows Applink was designed (only) to allow an EXE to call OpenSSL DLL; it does not work for a caller in a(nother) DLL. Exactly as you suggest, you can read the file yourself and call `d2i_PKCS12` (no suffix). DER routines in OpenSSL have 3 variants: `i2d_x` to memory and `d2i_x` from memory, `i2d_x_fp d2i_x_fp` to and from a `FILE*`, and `i2d_x_bio d2i_x_bio` to and from a `BIO*`. This last gives another option: you can call `BIO_new_file` to open the file *from OpenSSL's zone of the C runtime*, `d2i_x_bio` on that, and `BIO_free` it; that way doesn't need Applink. ...

Comment: ... See the manpage for d2i_X509/i2d_X509/etc. It lays out the options for X509; although not consistently documented separately for other types, the same pattern applies to them.