# no OPENSSL_Applink runtime error

Tags: visual-c++, openssl

An update to my question below:  I am trying to do something - anything -
to get d2i_PKCS12_fp() to work.  I am now calling it from a new dll that
is compiled with /MD.  There is no change.  Here is my code:

```
#include <openssl\applink.c>
CRYPTO_malloc_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
fptr = fopen(p12_file, "rb");
if (fptr == NULL) return(FALSE);
d2i_PKCS12_fp(fptr, &p12_cert);
fclose(fptr);
```

The call to d2i_PKCS12_fp() always produces the no OPENSSL_Applink runtime
error. If anybody can shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

--- original question ----

I am attempting to use the d2i_PKCS12_fp() API call in a Windows DLL
compiled with the multi-threaded (/MT) runtime library.  On this call I
get the runtime error "OPENSSL_Uplink(03CE1000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink".
From discussions I have seen about this error, I thought I could fix it by
adding "applink.c" to my project, and calling CRYPTO_malloc_init(). 
However this has no effect.  Is use of /MT causing this?  It will be
difficult to change that, due to other components of the project.  I have
used the HMAC and SHA256 APIs in this project with no problem.  If it is
just file I/O causing the problem, is there a way that I can
read in the .p12 file myself, and just pass a buffer to OpenSSL in order
to initialize the PKCS12 structure?  I am using MSVC 2010.

Comment: I believe `OPENSSL_Applink` is used to build the openssl applications - like `openssl enc`, `openssl dec`, `openssl sign`, `openssl verify`, `openssl x509`, etc. You don't use it when building shared objects and dlls. (And you don't build it when cross-compiling either, like Android or iOS).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting client certificate & private key from .p12 file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549459/extracting-client-certificate-private-key-from-p12-file)

Comment: Derived from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066318/how-to-generate-rsa-sha-signature-using-openssl-in-c  
and answered there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I saw on the web that `#include <openssl\applink.c>` was missing, but it didn't fixed the issue.
My issue was that I was working in debug mode and OpenSSL was **built** in **release** mode. 
**re-building** OpenSSL in **Debug** (using `perl Configure debug-VC-WIN32`) fixed the issue.
Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same runtime error when compiling a C++ Qt project using the OpenSSL library for TLS, on Windows. The release build was running fine but the debug build was displaying the runtime error: **OPENSSL_Uplink(0F7D26B8,08): no OPENSSL_Applink**

The cause of this error was a call to **ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr)** function.
After commenting the ERR_print_errors_fp everything was working fine.